# Expressão regular para reconhecer linguagem: palavras que não contenham "bbab"

Tags: regex, matemática, teoria-da-computação, autômatos, linguagens-formais

O [@LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/18246/linq) me desafiou a escrever uma expressão regular para reconhecer a seguinte linguagem `L`:

[image: Linguagem sobre o alfabeto desejado {a,b,c,d}, qualquer palavra que não contenha a subexpressão "bbab"]

Consegui montar, sobre essa premissa, a seguinte máquina de estados finito:

[image: Máquina de estados finito para reconhecer a palavra que não contém "bbab"]

> o [Miguel Angelo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1925/miguel-angelo) detectou um erro de digitação no AFD descrito originalmente. A transição `qa ->q0` se dá no caso `[^b]`, conforme figura nova; na figura antiga com `[^a]` estava errado

E, também, a seguinte gramática regular (recursão de cauda):

[image: L(G) = L, gramática sobre {a,b,c,d} que gera a L do desafio]

Já estou com essas informações em mãos, mas não estou conseguindo escrever uma expressão regular para detectar `L`. Então tenho os seguintes questionamentos:

- Qual a expressão regular (matematicamente falando) que reconhece `L`?
- É verdade que o regex é computacionalmente equivalente a gramáticas regulares? Ou gramáticas regulares é um super-conjunto próprio?
- Qual algoritmo posso usar para transformar o meu AFD em regex?
- Qual algoritmo posso usar para transformar minha gramática regular determinística em regex?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert AFD: autômato finito determinístico

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert conter `bbab` deve retornar falso, portanto a gramática não pode produzir essa subpalavra de jeito algum. Olha na máquina de estados que, quando é produzida essa palavra, vai no estado além da salvação `damnation`, a partir do qual não consegui ir para um estado de aceitação

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert eu posso ter errado no AFD ou na gramática, mas foi minha tentativa =] Posso revisar de novo, mas eu não creio que eu mesmo vá conseguir encontrar o meu erro, caso eu tenha cometido

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66330/discussion-between-guilherme-lautert-and-jefferson-quesado).

Comment: Se o input for infinito nunca haverá fim, e a única alternativa é eventualmente falhar. Se o input for finito, qualquer estado ao chegar ao final do input deve ir para a aceitação.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo `(aba)*` termina em estado de aceitação

Comment: Não entendi. Estava me referindo à máquina de estados... tipo, qualquer estado ao ler $ (fim do input) vai para o estado de aceitação.

Comment: Na última parte da máquina, no estado `qa`, porque está voltando para o início ao ler `[^a]`? Não deveria ser `[^b]`?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo sim, no caso, nessa modelagem de AFD não usei o fim de linha `$`, mas se tivesse essa marca os estados `q0`, `qb1`, `qb2` e `qa` iriam para o estado de aceitação após ler `$`

Comment: @MiguelAngelo erro de digitação, vou corrigir a figura assim que tiver acesso a um computador

Comment: Consegui chegar nessa expressão, a partir da sua AFD: `^($|[^b]|b($|[^b]|b(b)*($|[^ab]|a($|[^b]))))*$`... é o melhor que consegui! =D

Comment: @MiguelAngelo eu imaginava que ia ser grande mesmo, vou analisar com carinho =]

Comment: Mas um algoritmo geral, eu não saberia dizer, pois tive que usar `$` pra me salvar. É tipo um GoTo das regex, eu não achei outra forma de terminar subitamente o laço criado pelo operador `*`.

Comment: Boie bonito, que pergunta sinistra. +1 só porque não entendi, rs!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Bom vejamos que o Linguagem L aceita seguindo a premissa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- `{a,b,c,d}` - assim temos que os únicos caracteres presentes na linguagem são *a,b,c,d*
- `*` - todas as possíveis palavras que podem ser formadas por estes caracteres

Mas há uma regra :

- `p does not contains subsequence bbab` - Ou seja a ***palavra*** não pode conter a sequência **bbab**

Ambas máquinas de estados e gramática regular estão corretas, contudo quando você for montar a REGEX você pode ter em mente que apenas dando *match* em *`bbab`* já torna a sequência inválida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usando o [JFlap](http://www.jflap.org/tutorial/fa/createfa/fa.html) montei o autômato finito na qual podemos analisar melhor

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Gramática Regular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeLk0.png)

Se a linguagem que você está usando já possui as alternativas [***look-ahead***](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), torna-se simples montas uma validação por REGEX.

```
(?=^[abcd]*$)(?!^.*bbab.*$).*
```

- `(?=^[abcd]*$)` - vai aceitar apenas os caracteres envolvidos
- `(?!^.*bbab.*$)` - se encontrar em qualquer parte da sentença atual `bbab` ira recusar o *match*.

[Veja mais no debug](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ZFLJWZpBqL31g8Bk)

Agora que estiver montando em REGEX pura, que não possui *look-ahead* torna-se um pouco complexo montar a regex, pois o processo é baseado em aceitação e não negação ou seja sua sentença deve iniciar e ir batendo todos os estados possíveis ate chegar no fim da sentença, se qualquer estado não for cumprido então não gera *match*.

Seguindo a [REGEX proposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241285/express%C3%A3o-regular-para-reconhecer-linguagem-palavras-que-n%C3%A3o-contenham-bbab#comment495966_241285) pelo [@Miguel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1925/miguel-angelo):

```
^($|[^b]|b($|[^b]|b(b)*($|[^ab]|a($|[^b]))))*$
```

Esta se baseia em dar *match* positivo se baseando por inicio(`^`) e fim(`$`) da sentença.

#### Questões

> - É verdade que o regex é computacionalmente equivalente a gramáticas regulares? Ou gramáticas regulares é um super-conjunto próprio?

Na verdade elas tem relação, pois podem ser geradas por um AFD (**A**utômato **F**inito **D**eterminístico), contudo, como você pode ver na imagem abaixo, elas não possuem uma relação direta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte : [Expressões Regulares e Gramáticas Regulares](http://infocat.ucpel.tche.br/disc/lfa/docs/LFA-T02.pdf)

Se você tiver uma ER ou GR e converter para AFε - o que não é muito complicado já que o `ε`(movimento vazio) te deixa pular de uma transição pra outra sem problemas - não quer disser que você vai conseguir completar as demais conversões de `AFε -> AFN -> AFD` já que a cada passo você esta restringindo regras e dependendo da complexidade não sera possível realizar a conversão.

Em algumas fontes que encontrei é dito que REGEX se baseia em RLG (**G**ramática **L**inear a Direita(**R**ight)) ou LLG (**G**ramática **L**inear a Esquerda (**L**eft)), geralmente RLG. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13945932/3937493)
Mas na verdade é implícito, pois essas conversões serão possíveis.

> - Qual algoritmo posso usar para transformar o meu AFD em regex?

Primeiramente [converta-o para uma RLG](http://www.jflap.org/tutorial/fa/dfa2rg/index.html), e após aplique esta regra :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Original : [Steps to convert regular expressions directly to regular grammars and vice versa](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/68575)

> - Qual a expressão regular (matematicamente falando) que reconhece `L`?

Vou ficar devendo.

#### Adendo

[Autômatos Finitos Determinísticos e Não Determinísticos](https://prezi.com/eh2rdcjubv3y/automatos-finitos-deterministicos-e-nao-deterministicos/)

Comment: Com símbolos de começo e fim eu creio que seja válido matematicamente também. Para mim me atendeu perfeitamente