# Regex - remover elemento

Tags: regex

Eu quero deletar todas os caracteres menos as 3 últimas letras que estão em maiúscula. E outra coisa, como que eu faço vários regex juntos?

Comment: A teoria dessa questão é relevante: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241285/64969 ; assim, você saberá como fazer a junção de expressões regulares (sabor matemático), e também como compor o que você necessita

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o que você quer fazer? Como assim colocar vários regex juntos?

Comment: Poderia complementar com um exemplo para evitar possíveis  interpretações erradas?

Comment: Isto pode ser realizado utilizando `Wildcards` também, utilizando um `Like Operator`

Answer (score 0):

A sintaxe depende da implementação de regex que vc está usando. Mas um exemplo usando a sintaxe de js:

```
str.replace(/^.*([A-Z])[^A-Z]*([A-Z])[^A-Z]*([A-Z])[^A-Z]*$/, '$1$2$3')
```

Comment: Eu acho que o parênteses dentro do grupo está errado. Também creio que você desejava colocar o quantificador de 3 vezes depois do parênteses, agrupamento letras maiúsculas e etc. E também creio que aqui você não isolou as letras maiúsculas, eu entendi que a resposta deveria retornar apenas as 3 ultimas  letras maiúsculas

Comment: Isso que dá escrever código no celular (e sem testar) :D