# Regex para verificar se string não termina com determinados caracteres

Tags: java, regex

Estou quebrando a cabeça no site http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Estou tentando fazer uma regex que valide alguns `.txt` que não contenha os caracteres `JJ` ou `M3` no final da linha.

Por exemplo, tenho os 3 `.txt` com as linhas abaixo:

.txt 1

1. 4481;77831853;4461;60;CAD;VCP;M3
2. 4647;86940830;4847;35;FRA;VCP;M3

.txt 2

1. 3287;69872804;3297;37;ANT;VCP;JJ
2. 3827;72247849;3857;38;DEC;VCP;JJ

.txt3

1. 5634;7082850;5634;40;MAR;VCP;PZ
2. 4362;3882867;4382;41;PAU;VCP;PZ

Preciso de uma regex que não aceite os `.txt` 1 e 2, somente o `.txt` 3, pois os dois últimos caracteres deles são diferentes de `JJ` e `M3`.

Answer (score 8):

Quem me acompanha aqui no SOpt sabe que eu não curto muito [funcionalidades além das previstas para linguagens regulares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241285/64969).

A [resposta fornecida pelo @nunks.lol](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/249688/64969) usa o *negative lookbehind*, que não é regular no sentido matemático. Mas essa com certeza é uma solução ótima.

Mas eu posso fazer sem *lookbehind*!

### Expressão das palavras que não terminam com `JJ`

O fato de não conter essas duas letras no final torna a questão mais fácil. Só ver a resposta [dessa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241285/64969) para ver o trabalho que dá negar uma subpalavra em qualquer lugar.

Para não acabar com `JJ`, temos 4 alternativas:

1. A linha está em branco, portanto casa com `^$`
2. A linha contém exatamente um caracter, portanto `^.$`
3. O último caracter é não J, `^.*[^J]$`
4. O penúltimo caracter é não J, `^.*[^J].$`

Portanto, a expressão a seguir casa com isso:

```
^$|^.$|^.*[^J]$|^.*[^J].$
```

Feio, não é? Mas felizmente pode ser simplificado:

```
^(.|.*([^J]|[^J].))?$
```

> eu poderia ter simplificado mais ainda `[^J]|[^J].`, mas aí eu perderia o formato a ser usado na próxima expressão

### Expressão das palavras que não terminam com `M3`

Para não acabar com `M3`, temos 4 alternativas:

1. A linha está em branco, portanto casa com `^$`
2. A linha contém exatamente um caracter, portanto `^.$`
3. O último caracter é não 3, `^.*[^3]$
4. O penúltimo caracter é não M, `^.*[^M].$`

Eu poderia colocar a versão feia e logo em seguida a simplificada, mas também posso abreviar:

```
^(.|.*([^3]|[^M].))?$
```

### Juntando tudo

Para juntar tudo, tem alguns casos especiais a se levar em consideração:

1. Pode terminar em `J` se a penúltima letra for `M`
2. Pode terminar em `3` se a penúltima letra for `J`

De resto, aglutinar as listas negadas faz o serviço. Esses seriam o únicos casos não tratados pela abstração anterior.

```
^(.|.*([^J3]|[^JM].|J3|MJ))?$
```

Comment: +1 pela saída sem *lookaround*! A sua resposta serve em qualquer implementação de regex.

Comment: @nunks.lol se eu te disser que nunca aprendi o _lookahead_, acredita? Aprendi regex com _grep_, _sed_ e _vim_ e ainda não precisei desse recurso (que não pertence às linguagens regulares mas chamam de regex)

Comment: +1 gostei da parte `([^J3]|[^JM].|J3|MJ)`, dica você pode simplificar `.|.*` => `.*`

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert mas é aplicável? O `.*` vem concatenado com coisas no fim, já o `.` é o único caracter solitário. Não consegui ver a simplificação, mas no momento que conseguir eu adiciono na resposta

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado de fato foi erro meu, não daria para reduzir, eu bati o olho na `?` e achei que era para a parte do `([^J3]|[^JM].|J3|MJ)`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado acredito! Também aprendi regex com sed e uso diariamente na shell do Solaris (nem é GNU sed, não suporta um monte de coisa, tem que escapar parênteses, etc.). Uso *lookaround* pra facilitar a vida em casos de uso que suportam, mas tendo a esquecer que ele existe na maioria das vezes, também por questões de desempenho quando a expressão vai ser invocada muitas vezes por segundo (alias, vou adicionar esse apontamento na minha resposta)

Answer (score 6):

Utilize a notação de *"negative lookbehind"* para garantir que a string não termina nos padrões que você definiu logo antes da quebra de linha, ou seja, um `$` que não tem `JJ` ou `M3` antes dele. Assim, a sua expressão regular fica:

```
^.*(?<!JJ|M3)$
```

Detalhando:

```
^          # início da linha
 .*        # qualquer caractere, zero ou mais vezes
   (?<!    # abertura do negative lookbehind
       JJ  # sequencia literal "JJ"
        |  # condicional "ou"
       M3  # sequencia literal "M3"
   )       # fechamento do negative lookbehind
$          # final da linha
```

Exemplo no regex101.com: https://regex101.com/r/2loAEN/2

*(incluí algumas linhas com terminação variada em J e 3 para demonstrar que a expressão não nega mais do que deveria)*

Explicação interessante de *lookaround* em expressões regulares: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups

***Complementando***: uma questão a ser levada em conta quando do uso de *lookahead* e *lookbehind* (os chamados *lookaround*) é a performance. O uso de *lookaround* tende a utilizar um pouco mais de CPU do que o *match* de expressões regulares "tradicionais". Caso você pretenda aplicar essa expressão de forma maciça, com muitas chamadas por segundo, pode ser vantajoso utilizar métodos de maior "verbosidade", como a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/249709/20363) dada pelo @JeffersonQuesado.

Answer (score 2):

Complementando as outras respostas, segue outra alternativa: para verificar se algo **não** é alguma coisa, muitas vezes é mais fácil verificar se é, e simplesmente inverter o resultado. Então você poderia usar esta regex:

```
String[] strings = { "4481;77831853;4461;60;CAD;VCP;M3", "4647;86940830;4847;35;FRA;VCP;M3",
                     "3287;69872804;3297;37;ANT;VCP;JJ", "3827;72247849;3857;38;DEC;VCP;JJ",
                     "5634;7082850;5634;40;MAR;VCP;PZ", "4362;3882867;4382;41;PAU;VCP;PZ",
                     "J", "3827;72247849;3857;38;DEC;VCP;AJ", "AJ", "JJ", "M3" };
for(String s : strings) {
    System.out.println(s + " = " + (! s.matches("^.*(JJ|M3)$")));
}
```

A regex é `^.*(JJ|M3)$`.
Os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` são o início e fim da string, para garantir que ela só tem que está especificado na regex.

`.*` é "zero ou mais caracteres" (o ponto é [qualquer caractere - exceto quebras de linha](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)) e o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` significa "zero ou mais ocorrências".

`JJ|M3` é uma [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), que corresponde a`JJ` ou `M3`.

Ou seja, a regex verifica se a string termina com `"JJ"` ou `"M3"`. Portanto, ela serve para verificar o que você **não** quer. Por isso eu inverto o resultado do [método `matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-), usando `!`: se a regex encontrar um *match*, ela corresponde ao que você não quer, e vice-versa.

A saída do código acima é:

```
4481;77831853;4461;60;CAD;VCP;M3 = false
4647;86940830;4847;35;FRA;VCP;M3 = false
3287;69872804;3297;37;ANT;VCP;JJ = false
3827;72247849;3857;38;DEC;VCP;JJ = false
5634;7082850;5634;40;MAR;VCP;PZ = true
4362;3882867;4382;41;PAU;VCP;PZ = true
J = true
3827;72247849;3857;38;DEC;VCP;AJ = true
AJ = true
JJ = false
M3 = false
```

---

Um porém do código anterior é que o método `matches` cria uma nova instância de [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), e como ele está sendo chamado em um *loop*, são criadas várias instâncias. Mas como todas elas usam a mesma regex, daria para melhorar isso usando - e reaproveitando - uma única instância, criando-a fora do *loop*:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^.*(JJ|M3)$").matcher("");
for (String s : strings) {
    System.out.println(s + " = " + (!matcher.reset(s).matches()));
}
```

A saída é a mesma do código anterior.

---

Este caso também dá para resolver sem regex:

```
for (String s : strings) {
    System.out.println(s + " = " + !(s.endsWith("JJ") || s.endsWith("M3")));
}
```

O [método `endsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-) verifica se a string termina com determinados caracteres. No caso, basta verificar se ela termina com `"JJ"` ou `"M3"`, e negar o resultado.

Comment: Nem tinha imaginado na solução sem regex!

Answer (score 1):

Creio que esteja lendo o arquivo linha a linha, então usando essa deve resolver.
A regex mais simples que imaginei foi `(.*(?!(M3|JJ))..|^.)$`.

- `.*`: Aceita os primeiros caracteres da linha
- `(?!(M3|JJ))`: Verifica se a string contém os caracteres M3 ou JJ
- `..`:  Garante que haverá dois caracteres no fim da linha, senão o M3 e o JJ iriam passar
- `^.`: Permite que haja uma linha com apenas um caractere
- `$`: Fim de entrada, para garantir que os últimos caracteres aceitos são os últimos da linha

Comment: Não entendi sua resposta, ache ela confusa. Teria como organizar melhor o pensamento?

Comment: Ok, vou fazer diferente

Answer (score 0):

Uma abordagem diferenciada será justamente buscar pelo resultado negativo:

```
...

String pattern = "/(JJ|M3)/";
Pattern regexp = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = regexp.matcher(linhaLidaDoArquivo);

// Existe também o método find() para o objeto m
// o qual você poderá iterar e verificar quantas
// ocorrências encontrou no padrão fornecido
if(pattern.matches(m)) {
    System.out.println("O seu arquivo é INVÁLIDO");
else
    System.out.println("O seu arquivo é VÁLIDO");
```

Em outras palavras: você saberá e controlará o que você **não** quer que ocorra. O código acima busca pelas combinações (maiúsculas) com o padrão "JJ" e "M3" em qualquer posição da *string*. Caso eles ocorram dentro da linha lida, então as classes *Pattern* e *Matcher* irão identificar tal ocorrência. Se encontradas, o *if* retornará *true* e o tratamento do estado **negativo** poderá ser utilizado. Para os demais casos, você irá tratá-los com o cenário esperado e válido.

Comment: Eu nunca vi em Java compilar regex `/`entre barras`/`. Sem falar que o `negative lookbehind` do @nunks trata do que você propôs de modo mais elegante.

Comment: O método `matches` da classe `String` recebe outra `String` como parâmetro, mas você está passando o `Matcher` (ou seja, o código sequer compila). Além disso, o certo é fazer `stringQueQueroVerificar.matches(stringContendoPattern)`, mas vc tenta fazer o contrário. Sem contar que a regex está errada, conforme já disse o @JeffersonQuesado - apesar disso, a ideia de verificar se tem JJ ou M3 (em vez de fazer uma regex que verifica se não tem isso) é boa, tanto que fiz isso [na minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/408463/112052) :-)