# Filtrar quantidade de caracteres com SED ou grep

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, linha-de-comando, sed

Tenho um arquivo com sequências de caracteres
Eu preciso num primeiro momento filtrar por exemplo apenas as linhas que tem 5 caracteres
E num segundo momento filtrar apenas os que tem pelo menos 2 caracteres repetidos juntos
Exemplo: exibir aazyx ou zyaax mas não exibe azyxa
E em terceiro momento filtrar linhas q tenham pelo menos uma vogal.

Esse último eu sei que é possível, os outros dois eu não sei se é possível com sed.
Desde já agradeço a ajuda e atenção

Comment: De modo geral, matematicamente expressões regulares não tem memória, não poderia conhecer o que tem atrás. Isso só é possível usando alguns meta caracteres modernos (um pouco mais de detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241285/64969))

Comment: Agora, é possível sim prever quais são todos os possíveis casos de repetição, então poderia colocar em um grande grupo de "ou"s...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas supondo que você tenha um arquivo texto no seguinte formato:

arquivo.txt

```
abcde
aabbc
kkkkk
ggggggggggggg
ccdde
```

Podemos filtrar da seguinte forma:

```
cat arquivo.txt | grep -x '.\{5,5\}' | grep -E '(.)\1{1}' | grep -E '[aeiouAEIOU]{1}'
```

Obs 1: Acho que seria melhor usar **egrep** ao invés de **grep** pras expressões regulares.

Obs 2: Estou sem tempo para os detalhes, de um **man** no grep pra pesquisar sobre os parâmetros.

Comment: obrigado, simples e eficiente

Comment: +1 ou de modo mais compacto: ` grep -xE '.{5}' arguivo.txt | grep -E '(.)\1' | grep -i '[aeiou]'`

Answer (score 1):

Olá, boa tarde.

Espero que seja isso que você precisa :)

```
#!/bin/bash
vCharsVogal=(aa ee ii oo uu)
vCharsConso=(bb cc dd ff gg hh ii jj kk ll mm nn pp qq rr ss tt vv xx zz ww yy)
vCharVogal=(a e i o u)
for line in $(cat $1); #//$1 eh o parametro para o arquivo de entrada 
do
        #1 -Primeiro testa se possui 5 chars 
        if (("${#line}" == "5"));
        then
                #2 - Depois verifica se possui repeticao de chars vogais
                continua=1
                for char in ${vCharsVogal[*]}
                do
                        countChar=$(echo "${line}" | awk -F"${char}" '{print NF-1}')
                        if (("$countChar" >= "1"));
                        then
                                #3 - Se entrou aqui, quer dizer que jah possui vogal :) 
                                echo "$line"
                                continua=0
                                break
                        fi
                done
                #Se nao teve nas vogais, ai faz as consoantes
                if(("${continua}" == "1"));
                then
                        for char in ${vCharsConso[*]}
                        do
                                countChar=$(echo "${line}" | awk -F"${char}" '{print NF-1}')
                                if (("$countChar" >= "1"));
                                then
                                        #3 - Vai verificar se existe vogal
                                        for vogal in ${vCharVogal[*]}
                                        do
                                                countVog=$(echo "${line}" | awk -F"${vogal}" '{print NF-1}')
                                                if (("$countVog" >= "1"));
                                                then
                                                        echo "$line"
                                                        continua=0
                                                        break
                                                fi
                                        done
                                        if(("${continua}" == "0"));
                                        then
                                                break
                                        fi
                                fi
                        done
                fi
        fi
done
```

Comment: obrigado, a solução é boa tbm apesar de mais complexa que a do @Tom Melo. Contudo sua solução vai me possibilitar tb outras solução.

Comment: Falta adaptar um pouco o código para tratar outros caracteres. Quando vi a solução do @Tom Melo, confesso que tive vontade de remover minha publicação hahahha.  O lado bom é que a gente aprende dos dois lados :) Valeu!