# REGEX - Como faço para procurar por expressões que NÃO contenham uma parte especifica?

Tags: regex, pl-sql

Estou trabalhando com `PL/SQL`.

Através de `REGEX`, como faço para encontrar todas as expressões que sejam diferentes de:

```
 <cod_orgao_destino>9577</cod_orgao_destino>
```

Obrigado!

Comment: php, javascript, python, java ou c#? Se isso é um XML seria melhor trabalhar com uma LIB para DOM (Object Document).

Comment: Estou trabalhando com PL/SQL.

Comment: Com Xpath é possivel, mas não tenho experiencia com PL/SQL, mas possivelmente seja algo proximo a isto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19584903/1518921 ... creio que o Xpath seja `//cod_orgao_destinorow[not(text() = '9577')]` (o `//` é em qualquer nivel, mas creio que se vc tiver uma estrutura especifica seria algo como `/foo/bar/baz[...]`) ... faz tempo que não uso xpath, mas se não funcionar tente isto: `/foo/bar/baz[not(contains(cod_orgao_destino, '9677'))]`

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241285/64969

Comment: Conforme o @GuilhermeNascimento comentou, se for para trabalhar com xml é muito melhor utilizar uma biblioteca específica para esta funcionalidade, lembrando que o Oracle disponibiliza o XMLType e muitos métodos de leitura e escrita, que facilitaria muito sua vida.

Comment: A busca não será feita em um XML. Desejo fazer essa busca em uma string qualquer que contém essa estrutura. A minha dúvida é sobre como fazer essa varredura usando o REGEX mesmo.

Comment: Veja se a seguinte sugestão serviria, utilizar um "not REGEXP_LIKE(Texto , SuaExpressao, 'i')"

Comment: Depende muito mais do que você quer pegar do que o que você não quer pegar, se for por exemplo pegar qualquer coisa parecida com `<cod_orgao_destino>VALOR</cod_orgao_destino>`, mas que o valor seja diferente de `9577` então é possivel dar uma resposta, mas se o objetivo é pegar outra coisa além disso só você explicando melhor com um exemplo de um valor completo do que tem (formato) e o que quer pegar nessa sintaxe sua especifica.

Answer (score 0):

É possível graças ao negative lookahead (n sei como traduzir isso) "(?!abc)"!

Pode conseguir isso usando essa expressão:

```
^((?!<cod_orgao_destino>9577<\/cod_orgao_destino>).)*$
```

Achei um lugar explicando em detalhes: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Comment: A regex está correta mas e a aplicação em pl/sql